# What was the name of this book?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

in the 90's I read a children's/ YA book dealing with a boy who had to travel somewhere and he did so in a boat.

The book opened with a battle between the Anglo-Saxons and the Normans.

I remember a section of the book dealt with the boy walking into a magical life size chess set.

Thank you!

Comment: What was the time period of the book? I think chess was invented a couple hundred years after the Norman conquest. I guess the game had predecessors before that though.

Comment: I'm not sure. I read it in the 90's when I was around 10 or 11. I'm so sorry this is terribly vague.

Comment: That's fine. I suspect that the details you gave are enough to uniquely identify the book, but if you can think of anything else, more details are always nice to have. Personally, I have no idea... :-/

Comment: I'm going to read the tales of Prydain series and see if that's it